# Matrix decomposition into column vector times its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I would like to decompose the matrix,
\begin{equation*}
        \mathbf{C}=\sigma_w^2
        \begin{bmatrix}
            f_2^2&f_1f_2&0\\[10pt]
            f_1f_2&f_1^2+f_2^2&f_1f_2\\[10pt]
            0&f_1f_2&f_1^2
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation*}
into,
$$\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{f}.\mathbf{f}^T\sigma_w^2$$

Is there a technique to solve for $\mathbf{f}$?

Comment: Is $\sigma_w^2$ a scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the determinant of

$\mathbf{C}=\sigma_w^2
        \begin{bmatrix}
            f_2^2&f_1f_2&0\\[10pt]
            f_1f_2&f_1^2+f_2^2&f_1f_2\\[10pt]
            0&f_1f_2&f_1^2
        \end{bmatrix}
$

is null, the determinant of $\mathbf{f}$ must also be null.

Therefore,

$\mathbf{f}=\begin{bmatrix}
            f_2&0&0\\[10pt]
            f_1&f_2&0\\[10pt]
            0&f_1&0
        \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: may I ask what technique you used to solve this?  i am studying Singular Value Decomposition as a possible technique...?

Comment: In all honesty, I did not use any technique. Since the order of the matrices is three, the rank is two, and the matrices are singular (zero determinant), with little evidence I have come to the result.

Answer (score 2):

(Since OP did not mention what is $\sigma_w^2$, assuming it to be a scalar) This cannot be done unless both $f_1,f_2=0$. Note that the matrix $C/\sigma_w^2$ (assuming $\sigma_w^2$ to be a scalar) has rank more than or equal to 2 (the first and the last rows are independent unless $f_1=f_2=0$). But any such decomposition should have rank less than or equal to 1. So it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the column vector $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\end{bmatrix}^T$. If $C$ is the **outer product** $ff^T\!$ of $f$ with itself (as opposed to the inner product $f^T\!f$, which results in a scalar), then

$$
    C = ff^T
      = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}
        \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}
      = \begin{bmatrix} a^2 &  ab &  ac \\
                         ab & b^2 &  bc \\
                         ac &  bc & c^2 \end{bmatrix}
      = \begin{bmatrix} f_2^2 &      f_1f_2 &      0 \\
                       f_1f_2 & f_1^2+f_2^2 & f_1f_2 \\
                            0 &      f_1f_2 &  f_1^2 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

To find the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ al you need to do is solve the following system of equations.

$$
\left\{\;\begin{array}{ccc} a^2 & = & f_2^2 \\
                       b^2 & = & f_1^2 + f_2^2 \\
                       c^2 & = & f_1^2 \\
                        ab & = & f_1f_2 \\
                        ac & = & 0 \\
                        bc & = & f_1f_2 \end{array} \right.
$$

You might be interested in checking out [the wikipedia article for the outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).